# Is it possible for a two clients to send sensor data to the same webpage?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, arduino, sensors, pulse

Currently I am using a pulse sensor to get real time pulse data from a client (let's call them client A), and emitting this data to Client B. I'm using socket.io and node.js for this.

I want the other person (client B) in this chatroom to also wear another pulse sensor, and for that data to be visible to client A on the same webpage. Is it possible for another person to send remote sensor data to the same webpage, and for that webpage to display it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with socket.io and nodejs.

Have both Client A and Client B send the 'pulse data' to the server via socketio, then have the server send the 'pulse data' to the clients.